# dtrace replacement for fseventer?

Tags: command-line, dtrace

I think many of us have been disappointed with the effective demise of `fseventer`.  What is a good `dtrace` shell based alternative to `fseventer` that will display all full paths of files being accessed for a defined application?

Answer (score 1):

They're not quite a 100% fit, but if you'd like to monitor file access for an application I find a combination of `opensnoop` and `fs_usage` works well. Only `opensnoop` uses DTrace though.

Comment: Yeah, I have explored both of those rather heavily, but I fear that I'm not getting full path information at times.  Have you seen any indication of how thorough `opensnoop` actually is as far as actually getting the full and complete paths?  One thing I did not realize before today was that I can actually use `opensnoop` with a `-n name` argument of a not yet existent process name and it will then attach to the process after it is running, which may do the job.

Answer (score 0):

The command below finds files that have been modified recently. (It's not what the OP asked but it's mostly what I used fseventer for.)

```
mdfind 'kMDItemFSContentChangeDate>$time.now(-300)'
```

`mdimport -A` lists the names of other metadata attributes.

`kMDItemContentModificationDate` is taken from EXIF data for files that have EXIF data. I didn't have many files with `kMDItemUserModifiedDate` within the last year, but they were files I had opened with TextEdit, Script Editor, or Skim.

There doesn't seem to be a metadata attribute for access time. `kMDItemAttributeChangeDate` is defined as "The date and time of the last change made to a metadata attribute".